# Road Connectivity Analysis by field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, dissolve, connectivity-analysis

I'm currently trying to do a connectivity analysis of roads of a specific type. (how far can you get before encountering a dirt road?) Ideally, I want the map to look something like this:

[image]

It is basically a connectivity analysis by field. So each "web" should be merged as a single feature because the roads layer I have now is a bunch of independent road segments(features). I would do it manually merging all the features, but there are over 5000 features in this roads layer.

Is there any tool that can help?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

Run the [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool, where your Dissolve field is road type (i.e. dirt, asphalt, etc.). If you allow multipart features you will get a single feature for all the asphalt, another feature for all the dirt, etc. This means you want to make sure to allow for singlepart features.

You may want to delete the dirt features or other non bike-rideable roads. If you delete them prior to running Dissolve that will make Dissolve run faster.